# create_before_destroy on azure virtual machines without naming conflict

Tags: azure, terraform, virtual-machine

I want to use create_before_destroy in my terraform code for Azure VMs. I am already using a random_string to make the VM name unique. Though, when recreating the instances I am still getting the `already exits` error because the random-string is not changing for the new instances.
Anybody knows how to create a new unique name for the new resources so that they don't conflict with the existing ones?

```
module "naming" {
  source  = "Azure/naming/azurerm"
  version = "0.4.0"
  prefix  = [var.environment]
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = module.naming.resource_group.name
  location = var.resource_group_location
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "zone" {
  name                = "${var.dns_zone_name}.germanywestcentral.cloudapp.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
  name                = module.naming.public_ip.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  domain_name_label   = var.dns_zone_name

}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "record" {
  name                = "dev-psql"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.zone.name
  ttl                 = 3600
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip.id
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = module.naming.virtual_network.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "odoo" {
  name                = "odoo-${module.naming.network_security_group.name}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  security_rule {
    name                       = module.naming.network_security_rule.name
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = azurerm_subnet.odoo.address_prefixes[0]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "postgres" {
  name                = "psql-${module.naming.network_security_group.name}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "5432"
    source_address_prefix      = azurerm_subnet.odoo.address_prefixes[0]
    destination_address_prefix = azurerm_subnet.postgres.address_prefixes[0]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "odoo" {
  name                 = "odoo-${module.naming.subnet.name}"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "postgres" {
  name                 = "postgres-${module.naming.subnet.name}"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  delegation {
    name = "fs"
    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "odoo" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.odoo.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.odoo.id
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "postgres" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.postgres.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.postgres.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "postgres" {
  name                = "odoo-postgres-pdz.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  depends_on          = [azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.postgres]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "postgres" {
  name                  = "odoo-postgres-pdzvnetlink.com"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.test.id
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "postgres" {
  name                   = "odoo-postgres-server"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  version                = "16"
  delegated_subnet_id    = azurerm_subnet.postgres.id
  private_dns_zone_id    = azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres.id
  administrator_login    = "core"
  administrator_password = var.postgres_password
  zone                   = "1"
  storage_mb             = 32768
  sku_name               = "B_Standard_B2ms"
  backup_retention_days  = 7

  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.postgres]
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "public" {
  name                = module.naming.lb.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "Basic"
  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "publicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "test" {
  name            = "BackEndAddressPool"
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.public.id
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "probe" {
  name                = "tcp-probe"
  protocol            = "Tcp"
  port                = 443
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.public.id
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "https-rule" {
  name                           = "https-rule"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 443
  backend_port                   = 443
  backend_address_pool_ids       = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.test.id]
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = azurerm_lb.public.frontend_ip_configuration[0].name
  probe_id                       = azurerm_lb_probe.probe.id
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.public.id
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "http-rule" {
  name                           = "http-rule"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  backend_port                   = 80
  backend_address_pool_ids       = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.test.id]
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = azurerm_lb.public.frontend_ip_configuration[0].name
  probe_id                       = azurerm_lb_probe.probe.id
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.public.id
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "internal" {
  count               = var.cluster_count
  name                = "${module.naming.network_interface.name}-${random_string.vm.id}-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testConfiguration${count.index}"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.odoo.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "test" {
  count                   = var.cluster_count
  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.internal[count.index].id
  ip_configuration_name   = "testConfiguration${count.index}"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.test.id
}

resource "azurerm_availability_set" "odoo" {
  name                         = module.naming.availability_set.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  platform_fault_domain_count  = 2
  platform_update_domain_count = 2
  managed                      = true
}

resource "random_string" "vm" {
  length         = 8
  special        = false
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "odoo" {
  count                 = var.cluster_count
  name                  = "${module.naming.linux_virtual_machine.name}-${random_string.vm.id}-${count.index}"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  availability_set_id   = azurerm_availability_set.odoo.id
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.internal[count.index].id]
  size                  = var.server_type

  plan {
    name      = "stable-gen2"
    product   = "flatcar-container-linux-free"
    publisher = "kinvolk"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "kinvolk"
    offer     = "flatcar-container-linux-free"
    sku       = "stable-gen2"
    version   = var.flatcar_version
  }

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = var.username
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/core.key.pub")
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    name                 = "osdisk-${random_string.vm.id}-${count.index}"
  }

  computer_name  = "odoo-${count.index}"
  admin_username = var.username
  custom_data = base64encode(data.ct_config.machine-ignitions.rendered)
  # lifecycle {
  #   create_before_destroy = true
  # }
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "datadisk" {
  count                = var.cluster_count
  name                 = "${module.naming.managed_disk.name}-odoo-datadisk-${count.index}"
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = "256"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "test" {
  count              = var.cluster_count
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.datadisk[count.index].id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.odoo[count.index].id
  lun                = "10"
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}

resource "terraform_data" "machine-ignitions" {
  input = data.ct_config.machine-ignitions.rendered
}

data "ct_config" "machine-ignitions" {
  content  = data.template_file.machine-configs.rendered
  strict   = true
}

data "template_file" "machine-configs" {
  template = file("${path.module}/cl/machine-mynode.yaml.tmpl")

  vars = {
    ssh_keys = jsonencode(var.ssh_keys)
    user     = var.username
    port     = var.ssh_port
    db_host  = azurerm_dns_a_record.record.fqdn #azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres.name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use create_before_destroy module in Terraform on Azure virtual machines without naming conflict I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The `already exists` error typically arises when Terraform attempts to create a new resource with the same name as an existing one. This suggests that the `random_string` resource is not triggering a new unique string upon recreation. This can happen if the `random_string` resource is not directly tied to the lifecycle of the VM or if its configuration does not change between runs.

When I tried to apply the random string as an input variable name I have also gone through the same error when I applied the random sting to the VM name alone

**demo terraform configuration:**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = "vmvk-${random_string.vm_name_suffix.result}"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.example.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"
   storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy"
    sku       = "22_04-lts"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

}
```

[image]

This happens because as we use

```
 lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
      }
```

In the configuration when we attach the random string to the VM name alone and rest configuration remains the same and is attached to the preexisting VM. With this lifecycle module in the configuration when we rerun the configuration it tries to create a new VM with the new name where the rest of the configuration remains the same and already attached to the preexisting VM which ended up getting the error mentioned above.

From the error, it is clear that the random code needs to be applied for the main parameters of the configuration as well along the VM name then `create before destroy` can work without any issue with new parameters.

**My updated terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "random_string" "vm_name_suffix" {
  length  = 8
  special = false
  numeric  = true
  upper   = false

  keepers = {
    timestamp = timestamp()
  }
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v-bolliv"
}

# Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example_vnet" {
  name                = "demovk-vnet-${random_string.vm_name_suffix.result}"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

   lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

# Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "example_subnet" {
  name                 = "demovk-subnet-${random_string.vm_name_suffix.result}"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

   lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

# Network Interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-nic-${random_string.vm_name_suffix.result}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"

  }

   lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = "vmvk-${random_string.vm_name_suffix.result}"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.example.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"
   storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy"
    sku       = "22_04-lts"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1-${random_string.vm_name_suffix.result}"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
  }
 
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

when I re-run the code

[image]

[image]

[image]